# Restart a web application after it's recycled

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

Every time an application is recycled - the next visitor will have a delay in loading a page while the application is recompiled. How do I avoid that?

The site is hosted on a web hosting service, if that matters.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's hosted on Windows Server 2012. (IIS 8 ?)

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Comment: See "[application initialization"](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately those settings don't seem to be set at the web host. But from the links I understand that it's therefore not possible (because if it was - there wouldn't be a _need_ for `startMode="AlwaysRunning"` etc.). Thanks again.

Comment: You can always do it "the old fashioned way". Have a program that runs once a minute to access your site.

Comment: Why not precompilation?